# How can I define a class in R for storing user defined functions?

Tags: r, oop

I come from using C#, PHP, javascript, etc. To me, it makes sense to be able to do something like:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function myFunction($var) {
        echo $var;
    }
}

$myClass = new SomeClass();

$myClass->myFunction('test');
```

I want to do this with R - is there something equivalent to this to help avoid naming conflicts? every time I load a package it tells me there are functions with common names in other packages and I just want to do avoid this.

Comment: R doesn't have a strong namespacing system. If a name conflicts with another existing function, you'll get the warning. You can call them explicitly with `::`, ie `mypacakge::myfunction()`.  If you want you could store a bunch of functions in a list. `f<-list(x=function(x) x+1, y=function(x) x+2); f$x(1); f$y(1)` but that's not a very common structure

Answer (score 5):

R reference classes have that 'feel'

```
.SomeClass <- setRefClass("SomeClass",
    methods = list(
      myFunction = function(var) {
          message(var)
      }))
```

and then

```
> myClass <- .SomeClass()
> myClass$myFunction('test')
test
```

In many cases a different solution is to use the S3 or S4 object system, and to implement methods on existing or newly created generics. The S4 version might look like

```
.A <- setClass("A",
  representation=representation(
    name="character",
    age="integer"))

A <- function(name=character(), age=integer(), ...)
    ## constructor: type check / coercion, then create
    .A(name=as.character(name), age=as.integer(age), ...)

setMethod("length", "A", function(x) {
    ## getGeneric("length") to discover existing generic
    length(x@name)
})

setMethod("show", "A", function(object) {
    ## how to display the object -- existing generic 'show'
    cat("class:", class(object), "\n")
    cat("length:", length(object), "\n")
    cat("name:", paste(sQuote(object@name), collapse=", "), "\n")
    cat("age:", paste(object@age, collapse=", "), "\n")
})

setGeneric("toupper")                   # no existing generic; create one

setMethod("toupper", "A", function(x) {
    ## use default 'initialize' method as copy constructor; return a
    ## new (updated) instance
    initialize(x, name=toupper(x@name))
})
```

and in use:

```
> a <- A(c("fred", "ginger"), c(88, 83))
> a
class: A 
length: 2 
name: 'fred', 'ginger' 
age: 88, 83 
> toupper(a)
class: A 
length: 2 
name: 'FRED', 'GINGER' 
age: 88, 83
```

And the S3 version (note that there is no class definition, other than in the constructor):

```
B <- function(name, age) {
    obj <- list(name=as.character(name), age=as.integer(age))
    class(obj) <- "B"
    obj
}

length.B <- function(x)
    ## 'length' is an S3 generic, but hard to know
    length(x$name)

print.B <- function(x, ...) {
    ## 'print' at the command line contains body UseMethod --
    ## signalling an existing S3 generic
    cat("class:", class(x), "\n")
    cat("length:", length(x), "\n")
    cat("name:", paste(sQuote(x$name), collapse=", "), "\n")
    cat("age:", paste(x$age, collapse=", "), "\n")
}

toupper.default <- base::toupper

toupper <- function(x, ...)
    UseMethod("toupper")

toupper.B <- function(x, ...) {
    x$name <- toupper(x$name)
    x
}
```

Perhaps both S3 and S4 implementations of new generics on existing functions cause a message about 'masking' when the new generic is exported from your package, so that doesn't really help with your question. In the example above the functionality of `toupper()` available in the base package is retained even if your generic masks the original definition; problems arise in S4 when package A defines a generic toupper, and package B defines a generic toupper, so that the user needs to disambiguate `A::toupper()` to get the correct table of methods.